# Bound on $a_i$ given $v=a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Suppose $v_1,...,v_n$ is a basis of $V$ (an inner product space over $\textbf F$), and $f_1,...,f_n$ are functions $V\rightarrow \textbf F$ such that $$v=f_1(v)v_1+\cdots +f_n(v)v_n \  \  \  (v\in V)$$ Find $c\ge 0$ such that $$\lvert f_i(v)\rvert \le c\lvert\lvert v\rvert \rvert \ \ \ (i=1,...,n)$$ for all $v\in V$. All I have is that if $v_1,...,v_n$ is orthonormal we can take $c=1$

Comment: I don’t think that this is possible for every v in an arbitrary V. Consider (I’ll write $\alpha, \beta$ instead of $f_1,f_2$ ): Let $v_1, …,v_n$ such that $<v_j,v_i> = R$ and $v= \alpha v_i +\beta v_j $ then by assumption:$\alpha^2 \le c||v||^2=c \langle \alpha v_i +\beta v_j, \alpha v_i +\beta v_j \rangle = c( \alpha^2||v_i||^2 + \beta^2||v_j||^2 + 2\alpha \beta R)$

But this doesn’t hold if we choose $\beta$ negative enough. The argument above is for F=$\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I think i solved it: https://prnt.sc/26n9uwq